# I am getting "Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'" when I have the correct format

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Trying to run the following code:

```
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
      service.nearbySearch({
        location: {lat: resp.coords.latitude, lng: resp.coords.longitude},
        radius: 10000,
        type: ['mosque']
      }, (results,status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            this.createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      });
```

but the line type: ['mosque'] is returning

"Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2801, 7): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'PlaceSearchRequest'"

on visual code and not letting me run this ionic project. Can anyone help me? I checked the Google places API documentation and I seem to have the correct format and type too.

I am on 
angular: 4.1
Ionic: 3

Comment: Putting the string 'mosque' in brackets [] makes it an array instead of string. Try removing the brackets and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem above..

Turns out the interface for PlaceSearchRequest that the above code is trying to run comes from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceSearchRequest

so based on that you just need to define a string not a list. I guess previously the old API had a list as a entry point as the tutorial I am following seemed to use it.

So my correct code:

```
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
      service.nearbySearch({
        location: {lat: resp.coords.latitude, lng: resp.coords.longitude},
        radius: 10000,
        type: ['mosque']
      }, (results,status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            this.createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Code looks identical to your question? What changed? Did you mean it's suppose to be `type: 'mosque'` instead of `type: ['mosque']`?